# Error al cargar la pagina Angular 14 NullInjectorError: main.js:1 NullInjectorError: NullInjectorError: No provider for bt!

Tags: angular

le consulto sobre este error al cargar la página.
Si alguien me puede ayudar a resolver el motivo, gracias.
Lo registra cada vez que se actualiza

```
NullInjectorError:    main.js:1
NullInjectorError: NullInjectorError: No provider for bt!
at e.value (main.js:1:1385123)
at n.value (main.js:1:1388509)
at n.value (main.js:1:1388509)
at n.value (main.js:1:1388509)
at ai (main.js:1:1375178)
at Object.xn (main.js:1:1375316)
at Ue.ɵfac [as useFactory] (main.js:1:1578428)
at Object.r [as factory] (main.js:1:1391047)
at n.value (main.js:1:1389681)
at n.value (main.js:1:1388451)
```

Comment: En algún componente o servicio has de tener un constructor con un parámetro llamado bt. Angular no sabe qué valor ha de pasarle al llamar dicho constructor

Comment: SI, busque ese termno en buscar en archivos de VSC , y no lo encuentre, lo buscaré  en cada archivo- gracias